# Bug in enumerable.range?

Tags: .net, linq

I have this code:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
First = 6,
Data1 = 6,
Data2 = 7,
Data3 = 8,
Data4 = 9,
Data5 = 10,
Last = 10,
Invalid = -1
};

Enumerable<int> _myTypes = Enumerable.Range((int)MyEnum.First, (int)MyEnum.Last);
```

This creates an enumerable with elements from 6 to 15. I have equivalent code starting with 1 and it works as expected. This seems like a bug or very strange to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) takes a `start` value, and a `count` value, not a `start` and `end` value.

So you are telling it to start at 6 and take 10 units, hence 6-15.

Comment: Thank you. I just figured it out.

Answer (score 4):

Instead, call [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx), like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> _myTypes = (int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops I see Enumerable takes a count and not a start to end. This appears to work if start is from 1.